# Cant get this simple function to return anything

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

Im just trying to formate this list, currently the function accepts skills which is a comma separated list

`skills =  Mobile, iOS (Swift,Objective C), Android (Java), JavaScript, React, Data processing, GIS, Cartography, Web, Design/UI/UX`

`skills_array = ["Mobile", " iOS (Swift", "Objective C)", " Android (Java)", " JavaScript", " React", " Data processing", " GIS", " Cartography", " Web", " Design/UI/UX"]`

Im not sure why this function does not return anything

```
formatSkills(skills) {

     let skills_array = skills.split(',')
     skills_array.map(skill => {
     return <li>skill</li>
     })
  }
```

seems pretty simple so not sure what i could be missing

Comment: Because you're not `returning` anything from the outer function. Do `return skills_array.map...` (also, use proper syntax for wrapping a variable in a string)

Comment: Is this JSX? If so, please add the tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two functions. Your `map` function is returning a `<li>..</li>`, and your formatSkills function is not returning anything right now. Add `return` to the result of your map call to return that from the function.

```
formatSkills(skills) {
   let skills_array = skills.split(',')
   return skills_array.map(skill => {
     return <li>skill</li>
   });
}
```

Comment: thanks, this worked, not sure why someone voted you down

Comment: Not the downvoter, but it could have been because of the missing quotes around the string being returned, or the missing (I know they're optional) semi-colons.

Comment: @DavidThomas I think that it is jsx so it is valid not to quote the returning string